# XSD RegEx to only allow all chars from keyboard

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, character

I am trying to develop an XSD schema with type that will allow only chars from keyboard.

For example, I need letters, numbers and all chars from keyboard like !, ^, $, *, [, ] etc. were allowed, but chars like § and © were not allowed. So, I just specify all allowed chars with escaping for some of those:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="some_type">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
   <xsd:maxLength value="2000"/>
   <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,/&lt;&gt;\?;:&quot;'`~!@#%\(\)\[\]{}_\+=\|\\&amp;^$-*]{1,2000}"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

But when I try to pass a string like:

```
<text>this is test ^$- </text>
```

I receive an error, that this value is not the correct value for the type.
How should I fix the RegEx in XSD to allow all chars from keyboard?

Comment: "*[...] allow only chars from keyboard*": Which keyboard(s)? There are plenty of keyboard types; some of them have more than just Latin letters.

Comment: English keyboards with only Latin letters and special chars.

Comment: I have an English keyboard with keys for "§" and "±" and "£" and "€". You need to be more precise.

Comment: I need those chars except letters and numbers - .,_!@#$%^&*()-=+*/\|'"`№;:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the *character class intersection* syntax.

You can provide the range of values, and subsequently, which values of that range, should not be included.

For example, the following will match all letters, from uppercase *`A`* to lowercase *`z`*, negating the values *`[`* through *`` ` ``*, which reside within.

```
[A-z&&[^\[-`]]+
```

> *"... I need letters, numbers and all chars from keyboard like !, ^, $, *, [, ] etc. were allowed, but chars like § and © were not allowed. ..."*

You can just provide the printable *ASCII* range, to prevent the *`§`* and *`©`* characters, which are not within this range.
The range is *`!`* to *`~`*.

Here is the complete list of printable *ASCII* characters.
*[Wikipedia.org – ASCII – Printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)*.

```
[!-~]+
```

Comment: This works for me - ```[ №!-~]{1,2000}```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you need to escape the 4th occurrence of the `-` character in your XSD Regex (towards the end, just before the `*`):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,/&lt;&gt;\?;:&quot;'`~!@#%\(\)\[\]{}_\+=\|\\&amp;^$-*]{1,2000}
```

It should be

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 \.,/&lt;&gt;\?;:&quot;'`~!@#%\(\)\[\]{}_\+=\|\\&amp;^$\-*]{1,2000}
```

After that, your input: `this is test ^$-`  should validate fine.

Notice how at the beginning of your regex you have `a-zA-Z0-9`? Well the parser is probably interpreting the last `-` as another range, `$-*`, as if it says *`dollar sign to star`* instead of just `dollar sign, hyphen, star`.

I used Saxon and .NET Core 6 to test this by the way, and both times escaping the 4th `-` worked fine for me.

Comment: No, it passed EUR sign (€), but shouldn't.